# How to remove JMS queue messages through JMX console in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to clear queue messages from JMS where HornetQ is embedded with JBoss 7.1.1. I tried to login with JMX admin console but I am not able to do so. when I provide username and password, it is not going through.

Hence I created a new user using `add.bat` script as follows:

```
Realm (ManagementRealm) : ManagementRealm
Username : q
Password : superpassword
Re-enter Password : superpassword
```

But I am still not able to login to JMX console.

Can anyone suggest a way to login to JMX admin console and please provide steps to view and clear messages in the queue?